# Sprintf заменяет %d на [число]

Tags: golang, sprintf

```golang
func localize(id string, a ...interface{}) string {
    str := "test %d"
    return fmt.Sprintf(str, a) // Вернёт "test [5]"
}
```

На выходе нужно `test 5`, а не `test [5]`. В чем проблема и как лечить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли «рапределить» аргументы:

```golang
return fmt.Sprintf(str, a...)
```